# Pass Array Values using Setter to 2nd Form

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, getter-setter

- I have 2 forms
- I have a dataset filled with values
- I query the ds on form 1 and pull results, which is 1 column of information
- This info is held in an array on form 1
- I want to pass this info to the second form (form 2), into text boxes

Is there any way I can pass the info from the array to my second form without having to create multiple properties and setters?

This is my code, I am only passing 1 value (column) at the moment because I cannot work out how to pass multiple values.

Thanks.

Form 1

```
    //
    //SEARCH BUTTON
    //
    private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchFor = tbSearch.Text;
        int results = 0;
        DataRow[] returnedRows;

        returnedRows = ds.Tables["Table_Data_1"].Select("parlour_number='" + searchFor + "'");
        results = returnedRows.Length;

        if (results > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow returned in returnedRows)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(returned[1].ToString() + " " + returned[2].ToString());

                SearchResults frm2 = new SearchResults();
                frm2.ResultsProp = returned[1].ToString();
                frm2.Show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No results found");
        }
    }
```

Search results (Form 2)

```
public partial class SearchResults : Form
{
    public SearchResults()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string getResults(string result)
    {
        return parlourTb.Text = result;
    }

    private string passedResult;
    public string ResultsProp
    {
        set { passedResult = getResults(value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value using the second form class constructor

```
SearchResults frm2 = new SearchResults(returned[1].ToString());
frm2.Show();
```

Updating your second form in that way:

```
public partial class SearchResults : Form
{
    private string passedResult;

    public SearchResults(string result)
    {
        passedResult = result;
        InitializeComponent();
    }    
}
```

For last, you can add a load event in order to assign the value to the textbox:

```
private void SearchResults_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    parlourTb.Text = passedResult;
}
```

**EDIT:** Passing multiple values.

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();

foreach (DataRow returned in returnedRows)
{
    MessageBox.Show(returned[1].ToString() + " " + returned[2].ToString());
    results.Add(returned[1].ToString());
}

SearchResults frm2 = new SearchResults(results);
frm2.Show();
```

Second form code:

```
public partial class SearchResults : Form
{
    private List<string> passedResult;

    public SearchResults(List<string> results)
    {
        passedResults = results; // Then use your list.
        InitializeComponent();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Actually, yes, I see what you have done there, and that would work for me, though I would still be keen to know if i can use a setter for this also.

Comment: Yes, you can, it's still valid. However, with what I understand of your question, I would do a list of string and then pass it all to the second form. Check the edit to my answer.